# parsing arguments to jq filter

Tags: json, bash, parameter-passing, jq

Here is my config:

```json
{
  "students": ""
}
```

And my bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Default values of arguments
SHOULD_INITIALIZE=0
CACHE_DIRECTORY="/etc/cache"
ROOT_DIRECTORY="/etc/projects"
OTHER_ARGUMENTS=()

# Loop through arguments and process them
for arg in "$@"; do
  case $arg in
  -i | --initialize)
    SHOULD_INITIALIZE=1
    shift # Remove --initialize from processing
    ;;
  -c=* | --cache=*)
    CACHE_DIRECTORY="${arg#*=}"
    shift # Remove --cache= from processing
    ;;
  -r | --root)
    ROOT_DIRECTORY="$2"
    shift # Remove argument name from processing
    shift # Remove argument value from processing
    ;;
  *)
    OTHER_ARGUMENTS+=("$1")
    shift # Remove generic argument from processing
    ;;
  esac
done

echo "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[0]}" # ScheduleSQL.json
echo "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[1]}" # root
echo "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[2]}" # .students
echo "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[3]}" # Andrei

# PRJNAME='prj1'
#
# echo $PRJNAME
#
# jq --arg v "$PRJNAME" '.dev.projects."$v"' config.json
# jq '.dev.projects.prj1' config.json

cd "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[1]}"
# jq '.students += Andrei' ScheduleSQL.json
jq --arg entry "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[3]}" --arg destination "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[2]}"  '$destination[$entry]' "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[0]}"
#jq '"${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[2]}" + +=  + ""${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[3]}"" + "${OTHER_ARGUMENTS[0]}"
```

All i want to do is to fill "students" with a variable and i use `jq` for that, but i get this error:

```xml
$ jq --arg entry ".students" --arg destination "Andrei"  '$destination[$entry]' ScheduleSQL.json
jq: error (at ScheduleSQL.json:2): Cannot index string with string ".students"
```

Actually, want to do modify JSON and get:
Here is my config:

```json
{
  "students": "Andrei"
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq with variable for key and value:

```
jq --arg KEY "students" --arg VALUE "Andrei" '{($KEY):$VALUE}' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "students": "Andrei"
}
```

Comment: Ok,  yes, that work, but i need to define ".students" too.

Comment: How you said , it works: 
`$ jq --arg entry ".students" --arg destination "Andrei"  '$entry = $destination' ScheduleSQL.json
jq: error (at ScheduleSQL.json:4): Invalid path expression with result ".students"


$ jq --arg destination "Andrei"  '.students = $destination' ScheduleSQL.json
{
  "students": "Andrei"
}`
But with 2 arg, it does not work.